# Netty 4. Parallel processing after ByteToMessageCodec

Tags: netty

If a `NioEventLoopGroup` is used as a `workerGroup`, messages after `ByteToMessageDecoder` handler (for a single connection) are processed in a sequential (single threaded) way by following handlers within `NioEventLoop`.

Is it possible to make them to be processed by another «workers» after `ByteToMessageDecoder` handler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just add a `ChannelHandler` with a special `EventExecutorGroup` to the `ChannelPipeline`. For example [UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor.html) ([src](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor.java)).

So something like:

```
UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor executorGroup = ...;
pipeline.addLast(executorGroup, new MyChannelHandler());
```